# Accessing native resources of device using ExtJS 6 Modern Toolkit

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, sencha-cmd, extjs6, extjs6-modern

I have created Native mobile App by following -

http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/cordova_phonegap.html

I want to access resources of device like camera, GPS etc. in my application.

In Sencha Touch, there is package `Ext.device.*` for such activities.

So how to access such resources using ExtJS 6 Modern Toolkit?

Please provide the guideline and examples for the same.

Comment: I recently started a blog on extjs and made a post on this subject http://www.extjstips.com/2015/10/01/extjs-6-modern-toolkit-cordova-and-ios-native-apis/